# Embedded Implicit Loops in SAS with two Set Statements

Tags: loops, sas

I have the below code to track specific manufacturer coupon issuings.  Each issue can have dollars in the redeemed, expired and remaining fields.  I have an ISSUE table that gives all of the issuings and amounts and the REDEMPTIONS table that is an accounting of amounts redeemed or expired.  The objective is to track all coupon dollars for each issue by putting the appropriate amounts in each category.

This code is supposed to loop through the ISSUE table and tie matching records from the REDEMPTIONS table to each record in the ISSUE table.

```
/*create sample tables*/
    data ISSUE; input
    Coupon_NBR $  AMOUNT  REDEEMED    EXPIRED    REMAINING; datalines;
    A           500     0           0           500
    A           500     0           0           500
    B           500     0           0           500
    B           500     0           0           500
    B           500     0           0           500
    B           1250    0           0           1250
    B           750     0           0           750
    C           500     0           0           500
    C           500     0           0           500
    C           500     0           0           500
    C           500     0           0           500
    C           500     0           0           500
    run;

data REDEMPTIONS; input
Redemp_coupon_NBR $ TRANS_AMOUNT     TYPE $16.; datalines;
A                      -150       REDEMPTION
A                      -350       REDEMPTION
A                      -200       EXPIRATION
B                      -300       REDEMPTION
B                      -200       EXPIRATION
B                     -1000       REDEMPTION
C                     -1500       REDEMPTION
C                      -500       EXPIRATION
run;

/*begin looping code*/
data Tracking;

    if _n_ = 1 then Link get_redemptions;
    set issue;
        if (remaining > 0) and (Coupon_NBR = Redemp_coupon_NBR) then do; 
            if trans_amount = 0 then                
               link get_redemptions;


            if trans_amount + remaining >=0 then do; 
               remaining = remaining + trans_amount;
               if type = 'EXPIRATION' then;         
                  expired = expired - trans_amount;

               if type = 'REDEMPTION' then;         
                  redeemed = redeemed - trans_amount;

               link get_redemptions;        
            end;                                    

            else do;                                 
               remaining = 0;
               if type = 'EXPIRATION' then do;         
                  expired = expired - trans_amount;
               end;                   
               else do;                            
                  redeemed = redeemed - trans_amount;      
                  trans_amount = trans_amount + remaining;
                  remaining = 0;
               end;                                 
            end; 
        end; 

        else do;
            link get_redemptions;
        end;                                        

    return;


    get_redemptions:
    set redemptions;
    return;

run;
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
Coupon_NBR  AMOUNT  REDEEMED    EXPIRED REMAINING   redemp_coupon_nbr   trans_amount    type
A              500    150         150     350               A               -350    REDEMPTION
A              500    350         350     150               A               -200    EXPIRATION
B              500      0           0     500               B               -300    REDEMPTION
B              500    300         300     200               B               -200    EXPIRATION
B              500    200         200     300               B              -1000    REDEMPTION
B             1250   1000        1000     250               C              -1500    REDEMPTION
B              750      0           0     750               C               -500    EXPIRATION
```

In this example, the correct output is:

```
redemp_coupon_nbr   AMOUNT  REDEEMED    EXPIRED REMAINING
A                      500       500          0         0
A                      500         0        200       300
B                      500       300        200         0
B                      500       500          0         0
B                      500       500          0         0
B                     1250         0          0      1250
B                      750         0          0       750
C                      500       500          0         0
C                      500       500          0         0
C                      500       500          0         0
C                      500         0        500         0
C                      500         0          0       500
```

Obviously my result is far from where I want it to be.  My main concern, however, is that the output only has seven rows, when I want it track every coupon issue, which means I need it to have 12 rows (one for each row in the ISSUE table).  There is some kind of a problem with my loop I think specifically in the `Get Redemptions` definition.  I've been debugging for a while without success.

Comment: If you don't have any `output` statements then SAS will output at the end of the data step iteration. Sounds like your data step only iterates 7 times.  You just need to explicitly output the observations when you are ready.

Comment: Most data steps stop when you read past the end of the input. You need to not read past the end of `redemptions` before you have finished processing all of the records in `issue`.

Comment: Your output does not tell the whole picture, especially at the 3rd B where 1000 redemption is applied to coupon of 500, meaning there is a redemption balance of 500 (that is taken up in later coupons).  I would think in general you don't want to allow redemptions in excess of couponage.  You will need a fair amount of scaffolding to allow spinning over redemptions or couponage. The 'scaffolding' would be variables for a current balance, redemptionsum, expirationsum and redemptionbalance and expirationbalance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jarom:

A robust solution requires a transactional ledgering approach in order to properly deal with the alternatives of fetching multiple redemptions per coupon and tracking overages, and applying overages to a coupon before fetching additional redemptions.

The following sample code has numerous put statements so you can observe the algorithm decision points in the log.  The `balance` goal is to approach zero (from above or below) at each transaction reconciliation, and track any portions that go beyond the goal.

For the sample these variable names substitutions were done with respect to your data.

- coupon_nbr -> G
- redemp_coupon_nbr -> XG
- trans_amount -> XAMOUNT

You were correct in needing a `LINK` to fetch the redemptions.
The group wise processing is further facilitated by adding `BY XG` and `END=`.

Tests for the redemptions end= variable prevent a premature halting of the data step (which would occur if a subsequent unconditional set is reached after a data sets last record is read).

```
data reconciliation (keep=G AMOUNT REDEEMED EXPIRED REMAINING EXCESS APP_COUNT _redem_bal _expir_bal fetch_sum)
  ; * / debug;

  set issue;
  by G;

  REDEEMED = 0;
  EXPIRED = 0;
  REMAINING = 0;
  EXCESS = 0;

  if 0 then set redemptions; %* prep pdv;

  retain _balance   0;
  retain _redem_sum 0;
  retain _expir_sum 0;
  retain _redem_bal 0;
  retain _expir_bal 0;

if first.g then put / '----------- ' G= '-------------';

put '@set ' _N_=;
put 'balance: ' _balance _redem_bal= _expir_bal=; 
put 'coupon : ' amount first.g= /;

  if first.G then do;
    put @3 '@first in group';
    _balance = amount;
    _redem_sum = 0;
    _redem_bal = 0;
    _expir_sum = 0;
    _expir_bal = 0;

    put @3 'balance: ' _balance _redem_bal= _expir_bal= G= XG=;

    * spin to first matching redemption or first redemption in a higher by-group;
    if (XG ne G) then 
      do while (not EOT);
        link fetch;
        if XG >= G then leave;
      end;

    if (G = XG) then
      link apply_redemp; 

    put @6 'spin: ' G= XG=;
  end;
  else do; * additional couponage;
    put @3 '@next in group';

    if (G = XG) then
      _balance + amount;
    else
      _balance = amount;

    put @3 'balance: ' _balance _redem_bal= _expir_bal=;

    link apply_excess_to_balance;

    put @3 'balance: ' _balance _redem_bal= _expir_bal= xg= last.xg=;

    if (_balance > 0 and G = XG and not last.XG) then
      link fetch_apply;
  end;

  if (G = XG) then
    do while (not EOT and not last.XG and _balance > 0);
      link fetch_apply;
    end;

  redeemed  = _redem_sum;
  expired   = _expir_sum;
  remaining = min (_balance, amount);
  excess = sum (_redem_bal, _expir_bal, max (0, _balance - amount));

  output;

  put @4 'output: ' amount= redeemed= expired= remaining= excess= /;

  _redem_sum = 0;
  _expir_sum = 0;

  return;

apply_excess_to_balance:
  if (_redem_bal > 0 and _balance > 0) then do;
    apply = min ( _balance, _redem_bal );
    _redem_sum + apply;
    _redem_bal + -apply;
    _balance + -apply;
    app_count = sum(app_count,1);

    put @4 'excess: ' apply= _redem_bal= _redem_sum= _balance= 'reduced amount by excess redemption';
  end;

  if (_expir_bal > 0 and _balance > 0) then do;
    apply = min ( _balance, _expir_bal );
    _expir_sum + apply;
    _expir_bal + -apply;
    _balance + -apply;
    app_count = sum(app_count,1);

    put @4 'excess: ' apply= _expir_bal= _expir_sum= _balance= 'reduced amount by excess expiration';
  end;
return;

fetch:
  set redemptions end=EOT;
  by XG;

  put @5 'fetch: ' xg= xamount= type= first.xg= last.xg= EOT=;
return;

fetch_apply:
  link fetch;

  if (G = XG) then
    link apply_redemp; 

return;

apply_redemp:
  if type in: ('RED' 'EXP') then do;

    apply = min (_balance, -XAMOUNT);
    excess = max (0, -XAMOUNT - _balance);

    if type =: 'RED' then do; 
      _redem_sum + apply;
      _redem_bal + excess;
    end;
    else
    if type =: 'EXP' then do; 
      _expir_sum + apply;
      _expir_bal + excess;
    end;

    _balance + -apply;

    app_count = sum(app_count,1);
    fetch_sum = sum(fetch_sum, -xamount);

    put @5 'apply: ' apply= _balance= _redem_sum= _expir_sum= _redem_bal= _expir_bal=;
  end;
  return;
run;
```

Here is some additional sample data with

- non matching redemption
- B group has a first redemption which is a large excess that spans two coupons.
- coupon group with no redemptions

Trickier data

```
data ISSUE; input
G $  AMOUNT;
A           500   
A           500    
B           500    
B           500    
B           500    
B           1250   
B           750    
B2          100
B2          200
C           500    
C           500    
C           500    
C           500    
C           500    
run;

data REDEMPTIONS; input
XG $ XAMOUNT     TYPE $16.; datalines;
!   -1000       REDEMPTION
A    -150       REDEMPTION
A    -350       REDEMPTION
A    -200       EXPIRATION
B   -1100       REDEMPTION   was -300
B    -200       EXPIRATION
B   -1000       REDEMPTION
C   -1500       REDEMPTION
C    -500       EXPIRATION
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I see that I oversimplified the process.  Your solution works.  Thank you very much!