# FIFO Days Past Due logic pseudo-code in Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, sas, fifo, alteryx

[image]

I am trying to create some pseudo-code logic in excel for implementation in Alteryx/SAS/Python, but the logic is eluding me.

I have the debits and credits for a dummy transaction below, and I'm trying to calculate the Days Past Due (DPD) as at each transaction. In the real world, we'll have transaction dates too.

**Simple version of problem**: Columns D and E are my inputs. Column G is my objective. H is what we currently do, which is incorrect.

Our current implementation joins this data back onto itself so we are able to identify the oldest unpaid debit transaction - but future implementations can't use this logic since it's too big of a join with our data.

I'm trying to think of a more efficient way of doing it. One idea is to get the last X debit amounts and see if the cumulative unpaid amount is greater than the sum of the last 1,2,3,4... debits. Anything >5 debits we wouldn't care about (since they'd be >90DPD and this is the most info we need).

**Here's what I'm attempting:**

[image]

I'm trying to get the last debit amount (and the lagged version) in 5 columns (Q--U) but I'm not getting very far.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when there is a partial credit payment ?  Is the data presorted by customer id and transaction date (*day*) ? What are the maximum number of transactions (max N) a customer id would have ?  \_temporary\_ arrays can be used for tracking state if a large N is presumed, or a hash if a dynamic / unknown N is to be part of the implementation.

Comment: A partial payment means the debit is still due. The data is presorted by customer ID and transaction date, yes. At the minute I'm just trying to get the pseudo-code version working in excel without any VBA (just columns).

Comment: Please post data as text. Images aren't particularly helpful, especially when they're so small.

Comment: And do you have SAS/OR licenced?

Comment: I'm guessing you have several packages available to you given the tags. In Alteryx, it would be a combination of Multi-row Formula's and running totals. Ideal situation would be through an Iterative Macro though.

Comment: @KaneG - what's the iterative macro for here? Loop through each unique customer ID's transactions to perform the calc? Is that a big enough efficiency saving?

Answer (score 0):

With in group you will need to track the actual transactions (in arrays), the running balance, the 'paid' index of earliest debit with payment due remaining and rollup the 'paid' index when a credit is encountered.

For example, a SAS data step solution:

```
data have;
  cid=1;
  txid+1;
  input day type $ amt; datalines;
  0 DR 100
 30 DR 100
 45 CR 100
 60 DR 100
 75 CR 100
 90 DR 100
105 CR   .
120 DR 100
135 CR 100
run;

data want 
;*/ debug;
  array days[1000] _temporary_;
  array amts[1000] _temporary_;
  array types[1000] $2 _temporary_;

  set have;
  by cid;

  if first.cid then do;        * reset ledger tracking;
    call missing(of days(*));
    call missing(of amts(*));
    call missing(of types(*));
    tx_index = 0;              retain tx_index;
    balance = 0;               retain balance;
    pd_index = 1;              retain pd_index;
    dr_remnant = 0;            retain dr_remnant;
    days_past_due = 0;         retain days_past_due;
  end;

  * track ledger entry and update running balance;

  tx_index + 1;

  days[tx_index] = day;
  amts[tx_index] = amt;
  types[tx_index] = type;

  select (type);
    when ('DR') balance + -amt; /* debit entry, update running balance. tyvm says the bank */
    when ('CR') balance +  amt; /* credit entry, apply to running balance. bank is 'interested' */
    otherwise;
  end;

  if type = 'CR' then do;    
    if balance < 0 then do;  /* determine earliest unpaid debit after applying credit (FIFO) */
      cr_applied = 0;
      do while (cr_applied < amt and pd_index < tx_index);
        if types[pd_index] = 'CR' then continue; /* earlier credit entry will have already been dealt with */

        if dr_remnant > 0 then do;
          dr_remnant = dr_remnant - amt;
          cr_applied + amt;
        end;

        if dr_remnant > 0 then leave;  * do not advance pd_index, still chipping away at a single DR entry;

        cr_applied + amts[pd_index];   * CR covers DR remnant or an entire DR;
        pd_index + 1;
      end;
    end;

    /* fnd: /* find next debit where payment is due */
    do pd_index = pd_index by 1 while (types[pd_index] ne 'DR' and pd_index < tx_index);
    end;

    if types[pd_index] = 'DR' and dr_remnant = 0 then 
      dr_remnant = amts[pd_index];
  end;

  debit_due_start_date = days[pd_index];
  days_past_due = days[tx_index] - days[pd_index];
run;
```

You might also find [Embedded Implicit Loops in SAS with two Set Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498759/embedded-implicit-loops-in-sas-with-two-set-statements/49559424#49559424) somewhat similar and instructional:

> A robust solution requires a transactional ledgering approach in order to properly deal with the alternatives of fetching multiple redemptions per coupon and tracking overages, and applying overages to a coupon before fetching additional redemptions.

Comment: Hi Richard - I know it's been a while, but I'm actually finally trawling through this logic. What's the "fnd:" loop doing towards the end of the outer IF block? Simply jumping to the next debit where a payment is due?

Comment: Yes. The `do pd_index` loop is advancing through the `types[]` array until a non-debit transaction is found.  With robust data, non-debit (or `ne 'DR'`) means a `CR` transaction type.  I code for the case of non robust data in which there might be a spurious transaction type other than `DR` or `CR`